Is there a way to make this derived type work? TypeScript seems to be confused as to which type a parameter is
I am writing a micro-framework, so devs in my team have an easier time creating CRUD APIs. I wrote types to define Repository operations that can be added incrementally (using a builder, not included here), the types are CanFindAll, CanFindOne, CanCreateOne, CanReplaceOne, CanUpdateOne and CanDeleteOne. I then wrote a helper type Validators that takes a repository's type and returns the appropriate type for the validators that should be provided, it works for all cases except for CanUpdateOne, the odd thing is if I take the type hint from the type at that point, I get exactly the type I'm looking for, but for some reason when I actually use the type I get a different result.
Here are the types:
/**
 * An object extending this type can find all records of type `DTO`.
 * @template DTO - The type of the data to be found.
 * @template CanRead - The fields of `DTO` that can be read.
 * @template Data - The type of the data required to find all records.
 */
export type CanFindAll<
    DTO extends Record<'id', unknown>,
    CanRead extends keyof DTO,
    Data extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, never>,
> = Record<'findAll', (data: Data) => Promise<Prettify<Pick<DTO, CanRead>>[]>>

/**
 * An object extending this type can find one record of type `DTO`.
 * @template DTO - The type of the data to be found.
 * @template CanRead - The fields of `DTO` that can be read.
 */
export type CanFindOne<
    DTO extends Record<'id', unknown>,
    CanRead extends keyof DTO,
> = Record<
    'findOne',
    (data: { id: DTO['id'] }) => Promise<Option<Prettify<Pick<DTO, CanRead>>>>
>

/**
 * An object extending this type can create one record of type `DTO`.
 * @template DTO - The type of the data to be created.
 * @template CanRead - The fields of `DTO` that can be read.
 * @template CanWrite - The fields of `DTO` that can be written.
 */
export type CanCreateOne<
    DTO extends Record<'id', unknown>,
    CanRead extends keyof DTO,
    CanWrite extends keyof DTO,
> = Record<
    'createOne',
    (data: Prettify<Pick<DTO, CanWrite>>) => Promise<Prettify<Pick<DTO, CanRead>>>
>

/**
 * An object extending this type can replace one record of type `DTO`.
 * @template DTO - The type of the data to be replaced.
 * @template CanRead - The fields of `DTO` that can be read.
 * @template CanWrite - The fields of `DTO` that can be written.
 */
export type CanReplaceOne<
    DTO extends Record<'id', unknown>,
    CanRead extends keyof DTO,
    CanWrite extends keyof DTO,
> = Record<
    'replaceOne',
    (
        data: WithId<Pick<DTO, CanWrite>, DTO['id']>,
    ) => Promise<Option<Prettify<Pick<DTO, CanRead>>>>
>

/**
 * An object extending this type can update one record of type `DTO`.
 * @template DTO - The type of the data to be updated.
 * @template CanRead - The fields of `DTO` that can be read.
 * @template CanWrite - The fields of `DTO` that can be written.
 */
export type CanUpdateOne<
    DTO extends Record<'id', unknown>,
    CanRead extends keyof DTO,
    CanWrite extends keyof DTO,
> = Record<
    'updateOne',
    (
        data: Prettify<Partial<Pick<DTO, CanWrite>> & {
            id: DTO["id"];
        }>
    ) => Promise<Option<Prettify<Pick<DTO, CanRead>>>>
>

/**
 * An object extending this type can delete one record with id of type `ID`.
 * @template ID - The type of the id of the data to be deleted.
 */
export type CanDeleteOne<ID> = Record<
    'deleteOne',
    (data: { id: ID }) => Promise<void>
>

/**
 * A utility type that describes the request validators for a given repository.
 *
 * @example ```ts
 * type A = Validators<{ createOne: (data: {message: string}) => Promise<{id: string, message: string}>}>
 * const a: A = {
 *  createOne: (req) => ({message: req.body.message})
 * }
 * ```
 */
export type Validators<Repo> = {
    [K in keyof Repo]-?: Repo[K] extends CanFindAll<
        infer DTO,
        infer CanRead,
        infer Data
    >['findAll']
    ? (req: Request) => Parameters<CanFindAll<DTO, CanRead, Data>['findAll']>[0]
    : Repo[K] extends CanFindOne<infer DTO, infer CanRead>['findOne']
    ? (req: Request) => Parameters<CanFindOne<DTO, CanRead>['findOne']>[0]
    : Repo[K] extends CanCreateOne<
        infer DTO,
        infer CanRead,
        infer CanWrite
    >['createOne']
    ? (
        req: Request,
    ) => Parameters<CanCreateOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['createOne']>[0]
    : Repo[K] extends CanReplaceOne<
        infer DTO,
        infer CanRead,
        infer CanWrite
    >['replaceOne']
    ? (
        req: Request,
    ) => Parameters<
        CanReplaceOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['replaceOne']
    >[0]
    : Repo[K] extends CanUpdateOne<
        infer DTO,
        infer CanRead,
        infer CanWrite
    >['updateOne']
    ? (
        req: Request,
    ) => Parameters<
        CanUpdateOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['updateOne']
    >[0]
    : Repo[K] extends CanDeleteOne<infer ID>['deleteOne']
    ? (req: Request) => Parameters<CanDeleteOne<ID>['deleteOne']>[0]
    : never
}

If I then use the following ground types:
export type DTO = {
    id: string
    message: string
    createdAt: Date
    updatedAt: Date
}

export type CanRead = keyof DTO

export type CanWrite = 'message'

And I write a minimal repo, I get the following results:
const repo: CanUpdateOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite> = {
    updateOne: async (data) => none()
}

type Actual = ReturnType<Validators<typeof repo>['updateOne']> // { id: string }

type Expected = Parameters<
    CanUpdateOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['updateOne']
>[0] // { message?: string, id: string }

I don't know if I should just document it as a known issue and move on.
Playground

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is quite a lot of code and therefore unlikely to be a [mre]. Rarely is suitable example code longer than a few dozen lines. Could you please [edit] reduce this to the minimal example which demonstrates your issue?

(see prev comment) I'm trying to wade through this code and see what you're doing. It's confusing, since you aren't looking at the property names at all, like updateOne, which would seem to be the way to distinguish one property from another; Instead, you're looking at the property types, which are functions, and trying to figure out which one of them they are, but much of those are very similar. Functions are contravariant in their parameters, so (x: A)=>void is assignable to (x: A & B)=>void. So the function type for UpdateOne is assignable to that for FindOne; that's your issue.

(see prev comments). I'd be happy to try to come up with an alternative, or diagnose more clearly, but only if the example code gets a lot smaller. Probably you can get rid of Prettify and most of the different keys, etc. You're just trying to demonstrate the problem, not put the whole apparatus here. I'll follow this question to see updates. Good luck!

I was trying to come up with a minimal reproducible example, but I was having trouble finding where the actual problem was coming from, so no luck there. However someone at my company reached out with a similar observation to yours, the order in the Validators type was wrong, I needed to order the functions from narrow to wide, so after changing the order to CanFindAll, CanUpdateOne, CanFindOne, CanCreateOne, CanReplaceOne, CanDeleteOne, it now works.

The problem turned out to be that I ordered the conditional types in the Validators type wrong. After ordering them from narrow to wide (CanFindAll, CanUpdateOne, CanFindOne, CanCreateOne, CanReplaceOne, CanDeleteOne), it now works. Here's the correct type:
export type Validators<Repo> = {
  [K in keyof Repo]-?: Repo[K] extends CanFindAll<
    infer DTO,
    infer CanRead,
    infer Data
  >['findAll']
    ? (req: Request) => Parameters<CanFindAll<DTO, CanRead, Data>['findAll']>[0]
    : Repo[K] extends CanUpdateOne<
          infer DTO,
          infer CanRead,
          infer CanWrite
        >['updateOne']
      ? (
          req: Request,
        ) => Parameters<CanUpdateOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['updateOne']>[0]
      : Repo[K] extends CanFindOne<infer DTO, infer CanRead>['findOne']
        ? (req: Request) => Parameters<CanFindOne<DTO, CanRead>['findOne']>[0]
        : Repo[K] extends CanCreateOne<
              infer DTO,
              infer CanRead,
              infer CanWrite
            >['createOne']
          ? (
              req: Request,
            ) => Parameters<
              CanCreateOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['createOne']
            >[0]
          : Repo[K] extends CanReplaceOne<
                infer DTO,
                infer CanRead,
                infer CanWrite
              >['replaceOne']
            ? (
                req: Request,
              ) => Parameters<
                CanReplaceOne<DTO, CanRead, CanWrite>['replaceOne']
              >[0]
            : Repo[K] extends CanDeleteOne<infer ID>['deleteOne']
              ? (req: Request) => Parameters<CanDeleteOne<ID>['deleteOne']>[0]
              : never
}

